# Как реализовать вывод списка статей

Tags: java, android

Добрый вечер!
Каким образом реализовать вывод списка статей? Приложение получает JSON ответ от сервера вида:

```
{"id":1,"message":"Тут статейка","rating":"0"}
{"id":2,"message":"Тут статейка 2","rating":"0"}
{"id":3,"message":"Тут статейка 3","rating":"0"}
```

Всего статей в базе около 500шт. 
Мне нужно чтобы на страницу в приложении выводились 10 статей, при нажатии кнопки, эти 10 статей заменялись следующими 10-тью, и так далее.

Я думая для этого использовать ListView, но не совсем понимаю как заменять статьи при нажатии кнопки, ведь чтобы загрузить следующие 10 статей, приложение должно получить ответ от сервера с id следующих 10-ти статей.

Прошу помочь идеей реализации подобного. Или может каким нибудь другим способом это сделать.

P.S. Я не прошу код писать, а лишь идею реализации подобного!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Кроме текста статей обычно в json есть и названия. Их и показывают в списке. А сами тексты в другой Activity.
- ListView уже немного устарел. Вместо него сейчас используют RecyclerView.
- Следующая партия материалов обычно загружается, когда последний из имеющихся элементов списка появляется в области видимости. Новые элементы при этом не заменяют старые, а добавляются в конец списка.